# Conditionally mutate columns from char to factor in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to work using `ROracle` to query the Oracle database within `R`.

I have been able to store a table in an `R` `data.frame`, though I am facing the following issue.

Assuming the following `data.frame`,

```
my_table <- data.frame(name = c("a","b"), surname = c("h", "i"), stuff = c("as", "qweq"))
```

My objective is to find a completely automated line(s) of code that convert to `factor` all columns that are `characters` and which name do **not** contain the string `"name"`.

In this case, only `stuff` should be converted to factor.

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution: `mutate_at` takes select helper functions such as `tidyselect::contains`, which searches column names for a string and operates only on those. There's also `tidyselect::matches`, which is similar but takes a regex. In this case, since you wanted columns that *don't* have this string, I negated those column positions.

Note also that the default of `data.frame` is to make character vectors into factors, so these are already all factors.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_table <- data.frame(name = c("a","b"), surname = c("h", "i"), stuff = c("as", "qweq"), 
                       stringsAsFactors = F)

my_table %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-contains("name")), as.factor) %>%
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   name  surname stuff
#>   <chr> <chr>   <fct>
#> 1 a     h       as   
#> 2 b     i       qweq
```

You can omit the `as_tibble`; I did that just to get the printout with the column types included.

Comment: I like your solution, very concise and self-explanatory!

Comment: Though you forgot a very important condition in my question: the variables to change to factor must be characters and also not contains "name". How can I adapt you answer, please? Because as it is, it changes to factor all variables that do not contains "name" in their name!

Comment: Ah yes, I overlooked that. I'm trying to brainstorm some sort of `mutate_at_if` proxy

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do this, here is a quick example in base R:

```
my_table <- data.frame(name = c("a","b"), surname = c("h", "i"), stuff = c("as", "qweq"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_table[, -(grep("name", colnames(my_table)))] <- as.factor(my_table[, -(grep("name", colnames(my_table)))])
```

Comment: This solution throws an error: Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?

Comment: Does not throw an error on my end. Cut and pasted from SO.